# Stop moving cursor when touching scrollbar in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am struggling to find the settings for preventing cursor movement when I press anywhere in scrollbar. Because, for instance I am selecting the text and looking the similar cases in scrollbar (via Codeglance plugin), when I press anywhere in scrollbar cursor automatically goes to that line and my text selection resets. Is there any settings to prevent this? Please see the picture below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In order to prevent cursor movement we need to disable preview pop-up, then it works as expected. To make it : right click scrollbar and unclick "show code lens on scrollbar lens". Then whenever you select the text and move in scrollbar selection is not deselected automatically.